# Get all transient fields of class

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

How can i get all transient fields of domain class?

I need smth like this:

```
domainObject.domainClass.persistentProperties
```

but for transient properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`domainObject.domainClass.properties` returns a list of `DefaultGrailsDomainClassProperty`. These objects have a number of properties themselves, including `persistent`.

You can find all transient properties with:

```
domainObject.domainClass.properties.findAll { !it.persistent }
```